# Passing from Homology relative integers to $\mathbb{Z}_p$ loses topological information

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question

I just read that passing from Homology using the integers as cofficients to $\mathbb{Z}_p$ can mean embedding less topological information into the homology groups. Can somebody give me an example of a simplicial structure or CW-complex that whose homology groups lose information when these alternate coefficients are considered?

Comment: You mean $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ not the p-adic integers. If $A$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module then $A/ p A$ is a $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Comment: Yes, my notation $\mathbb{Z}_p$ was supposed to be the field with $p$ elements. Do you have an example for me?

Comment: With $X = \Bbb{C/(Z+iZ)},x=0$ what is $\pi_1(X;x),\pi_1(X;x)^{ab},H_1(X,\Bbb{Z}),H_1(X,\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})$ ?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not even sure how to interpret your space $X$, lol. What is the topology on it?

Comment: A complex torus, the simplest example of Riemann surface. Its fundamental group is generated by two closed-loops one of them is $[0,1]$.

Comment: Man, I don't know how to calculate those homology groups.

Comment: How does the complex Torus differ from a Torus embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: If you don't understand anything of holomogy group why do you ask ? $H_1(X,\Bbb{Z}) = \pi_1(X;x)^{ab}$ we make the fundamental group abelian because we are going to integrate some functions over the closed-loops and $\int_{C_1 \cup C_2} = \int_{C_1}+\int_{C_2}$. For an analytic function if $C_3,C_4$ are homotopic then $\int_{C_3}f(z)dz=\int_{C_4}f(z)dz$

Comment: A complex torus is topologically a donut. But with some analytic/meromorphic/harmonic functions on it making the first homology group natural and useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Klein bottle and the torus.

The first isn't orientable, so its $2$nd integral homology group isn't isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$.  The torus is orientable however...

Meanwhile if you use $\Bbb Z_2$ coefficients,  their $2$nd homology groups are the same ($\Bbb Z_2$).

Comment: Cool... I'm going to try to go through these calculations by hand tomorrow.